# Get the SourceLocation of the closing paren of an IfStmt in Clang in the presence of arbitrary macros

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

How do you find the spelling location of the end paren of an if statement in the presence of arbitrary macros? I'm trying to have a clang pass which, when given a line number, will add a "&& 0" to the end of the conditional (so all side effects are still executed)

Specifically, the test cases I'm looking at are:

```c
#define SIZE 60


  if (i > SIZE) {
    return;
  }
```

```
  if (i > 10) {
    //CHECK: if (i > 10 && 0)
    return;
  }
```

```
#define DO_CAST(y,x) (y)x

#define BIG_MACRO(x)      \
  for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {  \
    if (100 < DO_CAST(long, j + 10)) {      \
      break;                     \
    }                            \
  }

BIG_MACRO(10)
```

```
#define DO_CAST(y,x) (y)x

#define BIG_MACRO(x)            \
  for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {        \
    if (100 < DO_CAST(long, j + 10)) { \
      break;                           \
    }                                  \
  }

#define BIGGER_OUTER_MACRO(foo) \
  printf("bigger macro");       \
  BIG_MACRO(foo);

BIGGER_OUTER_MACRO(10);
```

In all cases, I'm trying to get a sourcelocation which points to the right parenthesis of the if line.

I've tried the following, and it almost works. Cond is the IfStmt's conditional

```
SourceLocation FinalTokenStart = SM.getSpellingLoc(Cond->getLocEnd());
SourceLocation InsertPoint = Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(FinalTokenStart, 0, SM, Opts);

// If the end of the conditional is a macro call, we will end up on the inside
// of the macro call's parens for some reason. Use this to get out of these calls
SourceLocation Next = Lexer::findLocationAfterToken(InsertPoint, tok::r_paren, SM, Opts, false);
while (Next.isValid()) {
    InsertPoint = Next.getLocWithOffset(-1);
    Next = Lexer::findLocationAfterToken(InsertPoint, tok::r_paren, SM, Opts, false);
}

TheRewriter.InsertText(InsertPoint, " && 0", true, true);
```

However, in the first case, it ends up with

```
#define SIZE 60 && 0


  if (i > SIZE) {
    return;
  }
```

Does anyone have any advice?